# Получение доступа к конкретному элементу

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

```
$query ="SELECT `head` FROM `comi`";
```

Который мне возвращает столбец head.

Как мне получить доступ к, например, 3 строке возвращенного массива без использования `while`?

Как сделать тоже самое если запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT * FROM `comi`
```

То есть запросить все, а выдернуть одно конкретное значение из 3 строки столбца `head`.

```
$Row=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, $query));
echo $Row['head'];
```

Зачем? Надо в учебных целях.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: замечу, что если вам в принципе надо только третий элемент, то можно выбрать из БД только третью строку, используя `limit 3,1` однако, не стоит забывать и о сортировке результатов.

Comment: @teran, без изменения запроса. Нужен принцип получения любого значения при условии, что запрашивался весь столбец

Comment: @rjhdby думаю стоит оформить в виде ответа.

Comment: Учебные цели бывают разные. Для чего конкретно эта? Откуда берется цифра 3 и что потом с этим значением будет происходить?

Answer (score -1):

Для этого существует функция [mysqli_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Только надо иметь в виду, что работает она с буферизованными результатами. Т.е. с результатами возвращаемыми `mysqli_query()`, или, в случае подготовленных запросов, после применения `mysqli_store_result()`.

Answer (score -1):

Не надо использовать ересь типа mysqli_data_seek. Так никто никогда не делает.

Во-первых, потому что надо использовать PDO вместо mysqli.
Во-вторых, потому что для обращения по индексу служат **массивы**.

Поэтому если нам нужна только одна запись, то выбираем только её **средствами SQL.**

```
$head = $pdo->query("SELECT `head` FROM `comi` LIMIT 3,1")->fetchColumn();
echo $head;
```

Если же нужны все записи к которым потом обращаемся по индексу, то получаем их в массив, с которым дальше и работаем:

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT `head` FROM `comi`")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo $data[2];
```

Comment: Вы бы, уважаемый, за всех не говорили. Задачи и контекст их решения бывает очень разный. Я могу на раз-два привести пример задачи, которая оптимальным образом будет решаться именно с помощью data_seek